using spring security 6.2.4 but I can't find the hasScope check in HttpSecurity
According to this documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/jwt.html
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.authorization.OAuth2AuthorizationManagers.hasScope

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
class MyCustomSecurityConfiguration {
    @Bean
    open fun filterChain(http: HttpSecurity): SecurityFilterChain {
        http {
            authorizeRequests {
                authorize("/messages/**", hasScope("message:read"))
                authorize(anyRequest, authenticated)
            }
            oauth2ResourceServer {
                jwt {
                    jwtAuthenticationConverter = myConverter()
                }
            }
        }
        return http.build()
    }
}

However, the authorizeRequests is deprecated but anyway it does not contain the authorize method and no hasScope.
I tried also with authorizeHttpRequests and no luck. please see my attached screenshot.

Can you please explain to me what am I missing?
Thank you.

As I also see there is no way having:
authorize("/messages/**", hasScope("message:read"))

But I could suggest having something like:
authorize("/messages/**", hasAuthority("SCOPE_message:read"))


Thank you. I don't even have the option to use the authorize method. I am using springboot 3.2.5.
but I can definitely use requestMatchers("/hello").hasAnyAuthority("SCPOPE_message:read")

Howeverm, I don't understand their change and why they removed these methods and I could not find any information about that
